# Jackson annotation mixin framework

Tags: annotations, jackson, mixins

Can the Jackson code that handles annotation mixins be reused by third-parties to mixin non-Jackson annotations?

What are the core Jackson classes that process mixins?

Comment: what do you want to do? please explain a little bit more: "mixin non-Jackson annotations"?

Comment: I want to be able to use mixins for non-Jackson annotations, and, from my own code that processes the non-Jackson annotations, use some library to obtain the annotations on a certain target, either directly on that target (as per normal JDK annotation rules), or on a mixin registered with the library for that target.  Jackson handles mixins, but I wasn't sure if its mixin functionality was usable for other annotations outside of Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the interface [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.ContextualSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/ContextualSerializer.html) and/or [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ContextualDeserializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/ContextualDeserializer.html). Jackson serializes and deserializes JSON. If this is not your intention, you will get some overhead and another approach could be better (e.g. a solution with [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/)).

If you are interested in the implementation of Jackson and how the (de)serializers are used:

> [This project](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) contains the general-purpose data-binding functionality and tree-model for Jackson Data Processor. It builds on core streaming parser/generator package, and uses Jackson Annotations for configuration.

A good entry point for analysis: [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java)

This code demonstrates the use of a custom annotation (used in a mixin) and how a suitable (de)serializer could be implemented:

```java
public class MyBean {

    private String value;
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

/////

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JacksonAnnotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotation // important so that it will get included!
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    public String value();
}

/////

public abstract class MyMixin {

    @MyAnnotation("Hello")
    public abstract String getValue();
}

/////

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ContextualDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String>  implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private String annoValue;

    public MyDeserializer(){}
    public MyDeserializer(MyAnnotation ann) {
        annoValue = ann.value();
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String serializedValue = p.getText();
        return serializedValue.substring(annoValue.length() + 1, serializedValue.length() - 1);
    }

    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty prop) throws JsonMappingException {

        MyAnnotation ann = prop.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        if (ann == null) {
            ann = prop.getContextAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        }
        if (ann == null) {
            return new StringDeserializer();
        }
        return new MyDeserializer(ann);
    }

}

/////

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.ContextualSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MySerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> implements ContextualSerializer {

    private String annoValue;

    public MySerializer() {}
    public MySerializer(MyAnnotation ann) {
        annoValue = ann.value();
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(String toSerialize, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider prov) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(annoValue + " " + toSerialize + "!");
    }

    public JsonSerializer createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty prop) throws JsonMappingException {

        MyAnnotation ann = prop.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        if (ann == null) {
            ann = prop.getContextAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        }
        if (ann == null) {
            return new StringSerializer();
        }
        return new MySerializer(ann);

    }
}

/////

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(String.class, new MySerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(String.class, new MyDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        mapper.addMixIn(MyBean.class, MyMixin.class);
        MyBean bean = new MyBean();
        bean.setValue("World");
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
        System.out.println(jsonInString);
        MyBean deserialized = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, MyBean.class);
        System.out.println(deserialized.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not asking about how to use Jackson, or Jackson's mixins. I already know that. I'm asking if the code that Jackson itself uses to handle annotation mixins can be easily used by others to handle annotation mixins for purposes other than Jackson.

Comment: yes, and that was my answer. MyDeserializer:: deserialize and MySerializer:: serialize could do all what you want.